# Can someone please give me a hint on how to draw velocity triangles for this specific inward flow reaction turbine problem?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, turbines

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the hydraulic efficiency for this turbine by using the formula:
E(hyd) = (Vw*U)/g*H
where  Vw= Velocity of whirl at inlet, U=velocity of runner at inlet, H=Given Head, and g=acceleration due to gravity.

But every time I get the efficiency more than 1 (which of course isn't possible).

I have tried this multiple but everytime it is more than 1. So I'd really appreciate if someone would properly guide me on how to make velocity triangles for this specific problem. Thanks.[image: I have added my own calulations here so please let me know where I'm wrong.]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the work that you have done so far.  It's understood that your work is incorrect, but seeing your work would allow someone to spot and correct the mistake you made.  The question can be re-opened once you have edited that in.

Comment: Thank you for adding in your work.  I have re-opened your question.  In the future, it is better to write out the work instead of posting a photo as users with mobile devices do not automatically see images.